# Getting the value of a cell in a jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I would like to loop through a jqGrid so that I can get the value of cell for futher logical processing.

```
var ids = $("#list").getGridParam("reccount")
alert(ids);
var v = 1;
 for(var i = 0; i < ids ; i++){
    amountvalue = $("#list").getCell(v,"amount");           
    alert(amountvalue);
    v = v + 1;
}
```

Strangely as obvious as it seems I am not getting the values as expected.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the values of all column cells value try this code

```
$("#list").getCol('amount');
```

or

```
var amountvalue = new Array(ids.length);

var ids = $("#list").getGridParam("reccount")

 for(var i = 0; i < ids ; i++){
    amountvalue[i] = $("#list").getCell(i,"amount");           
    alert(amountvalue[i]);

}
```

and if you want to get a value of specific cell then use this

```
var amountvalue = $("#list").getCell(5,"amount");
```